# postgresql, перевод числа во время

Tags: sql, postgresql

Подскажите пожалуйста:

Имеется:  колонка seconds, в которой хранятся числа тип int.

Нужно: получить колонку times, тип time without time zone.

Пример: seconds(26620) --> times(07:23:40)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужна функция `make_interval`:

```
select make_interval(secs => seconds)::time without time zone as times 
from tbl;
```

Comment: спасибо большое, все работает !